# Primitive completion Error

Tags: pallet, runtime, node-primitives

I have been running into a compilation error when adding different features in our node. This error appeared when I added the vesting pallet. It also appeared when I was configuring the runtime for something completely separate a month ago. The issue is I have no idea what is causing it since it doesn't point to any place for error. A copy of the error message can be seen below:

```
error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /Users/jackson/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/22d40c7/primitives/npos-elections/src/lib.rs:367:45
    |
367 |         Self { total: Default::default(), voters: vec![] }
    |                                                   ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            crate::sp_std::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /Users/jackson/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/22d40c7/primitives/npos-elections/src/reduce.rs:608:21
    |
608 |                     let min_edge = vec![min_voter, min_target];
    |                                    ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            crate::sp_std::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
  --> /Users/jackson/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/22d40c7/primitives/npos-elections/src/phragmms.rs:52:20
   |
52 |     let mut winners = vec![];
   |                       ^^^
   |
   = note: consider importing one of these items:
           codec::alloc::vec
           crate::sp_std::vec
           scale_info::prelude::vec
           sp_std::vec

error: could not compile `sp-npos-elections` due to 3 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have no idea what the possible causes are.

Comment: have you tried adding `use sp_std::prelude::*;`  to the top of the pallet to import the vector type? see docs: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_std/prelude/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by some format errors when configuring the runtime for the pallet I added. The first issue was the pallet was not imported and the second is when I used asterisks instead of quotes for the std configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).